# ¿Porque no se almacenan correctamente las palabras en los arrays?

Tags: java, array

El objetivo de este programa es que dada una secuencia de caracteres introducida verificar si alguna palabra es un palindromo (palabra que es simétrica de derecha a izquierda: qwewq qweewq) una vez verificado que es un palindromo contar el numero de letras para ver si la palabra es par o impar. Si **NumeroPalabrasPar < NumeroPalabrasImpar** se imprimirán solo los **palindromos impares** y viceversa. En el caso de que haya el mismo numero de pares e impares se imprimirán todos los palindromos (esto esta aun por desarrollar, no hagáis mucho caso a la parte final del programa)

Mi problema es que solo me imprime la ultima palabra introducida, yo creo que el fallo esta en los arrays. No voy a colgar los métodos y clases que uso, ya que solo me interesa saber si hay un fallo a la hora de almacenar.

```
public class PalindromosParesImpares{

    static final int MAXIMO_PALABRAS = 500;
    static int contadorP = 0;
    static int contadorI = 0;
    static final int MAXIMO = 20 + 1;
    static Palabra[] palabraspar = new Palabra[MAXIMO_PALABRAS];
    static Palabra[] palabrasim = new Palabra[MAXIMO_PALABRAS];
    static char[] palabra = new char[MAXIMO];
    static int numCaracteres;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.print("Introduce la secuencia de palabras: ");
        Palabra pal=new Palabra();

        //HAY PALABRAS
        while (Palabra.hayPalabras()) {

            //LEER PALABRAS
            pal.lectura();

            //Es palindromo
            if (pal.esPalindromo()) {

                //Palabra PAR
                if (pal.palabraPar()) {
                    palabraspar[contadorP] = pal;
                    contadorP++;
                }

                //Palabra IMPAR
                if (!pal.palabraPar()) {
                    palabrasim[contadorI] = pal;
                    contadorI++;
                }

            }

        }

        //Si hay mas PARES que IMPARES se imprimiran las palabras pares
        if (contadorI < contadorP) {

            System.out.println("Las palabras palindromos pares son: ");
            for (int indice = 0; indice < contadorP; indice++) {
                System.out.println(palabraspar[indice]);
            }

        }

        //Si hay mas IMPARES que PARES se imprimiran las palabras impares
        if (contadorP < contadorI) {

            System.out.println("Las palabras palindromos impares son: ");
            for (int indice = 0; indice < contadorI; indice++) {
                System.out.println(palabrasim[indice]);
            }

        }
        //Aun por modificar
        if (contadorP == contadorI) {
            System.out.println("No hay palindromos");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: El maximo de palabras en el texto es de 500 palabras, y el maximo de caracteres por palabra es de 20+1

Comment: No pongas "[Resuelto]" ni nada de eso. Así no funciona el sitio. Te recomiendo revisar el [tour]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es un clásico...

Supongo que en `Palabra` lees una palabra y la guardas.

Pero en el array no estás guardando `String`. Estás guardando `Palabra`. **Y SÓLO CREAS UNA INSTANCIA DE PALABRA**.

Así que siempre guardas el mismo objeto `Palabra` que, por lo que veo del código, sólo guarda la última.

Así, en todas las posiciones del array tienes el mismo objeto, lo que te da el resultado que estás viendo.

Solución: crea (y usa) una instancia distinta de `Palabra` para cada iteración.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesto, justo 2min antes de tu respuesta lo he conseguido resolver. Igualmente muchas gracias por la aportación.